# How can we set text to include button in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout

I create layout button and i want to use it to other place by include it and i want to change it text in per layout , is there a way??

my button(row_addbutton) :

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_banklist_addtoken"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundbutton_withradiusandcolorprimarylight"
    android:text="@string/banklist_addtoken"
    style="@style/TextAppearanceButton"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/addtokenicon"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/addtokenicon"
    android:paddingStart="60dp"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

</Button>
```

include it here :

```
<include
            layout="@layout/row_addtoken"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout_banklist_basecontent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
//is there any way to change text button here??
            />
```

Comment: No, i don't think that's possible.

Comment: but you can change text programmatically

Comment: @JeelVankhede But we can change on some fields like margin_top!

Comment: @appersiano ,Yeah ,i know it

Comment: @miladsalimi In alternative create your custom view and then you can change it via xml

Comment: @miladsalimi *But we can change on some fields like margin_top* because the `<include/>` support `all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes)`

Comment: @NileshRathod ,Yeah , i know ,thanks

Answer (score 3):

A more sensible way to achieve what you want is to declare a style for such buttons in `/res/values/styles.xml`. So then you just have to choose your style from the drop-down list and change the button text as you usually do.

Comment: So ,in per situation that we want to include ,we have to create new style for per button?!

Comment: No, you create a style only once, then use it for all the buttons you want. Then you can edit all the buttons of the same style from one place, that's the point. One style for one kind of buttons.

Comment: All of us know it , we try to find a way that involved include ,thank you but i think its not good answer until now

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the view of included layout.

You can do it in .java class like this.
Let's assume you have included your layout in activity_main.xml then go to  respective java file and in that you can do code like below :

```
 Button button_banklist_addtoken = findViewById(R.id. button_banklist_addtoken);
 button_banklist_addtoken.setText("Here is your text")
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you but we want to find a way in layout or xml